# Starting with Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I just started with the documentation of Scrapy and I was wondering if anyone could provide me with a proper line by line explanation of the following code:

```
 def parse(self, response):
     filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
     with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
         f.write(response.body)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen http://doc.scrapy.org/en/stable/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider?

> parse(): a method of the spider, which will be called with the downloaded Response object of each start URL. The response is passed to the method as the first and only argument.

```
# a method called parse that takes one argument: response 
def parse(self, response):
   # get the URL (string) from the response object [1]
   # split [2] the string on the "/" character
   # generate a filename from the list of split strings
   filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
   # open [3] a file called filename and write [4] into it the body
   # of the response (i.e. the contents of the scraped page) 
   with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
       f.write(response.body)
```

[1] http://doc.scrapy.org/en/stable/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response

[2] https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

[3] https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

[4] https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write

Answer (score 1):

You have a spider which downloads a web page and save the response in a file. 
The spider  applies as a callback for the response received the `parse` method that you defined:

line1: define parse method which receive the response as parameter. The response is what you get from the webserver.

line2: define a filename in which the response data will be saved. The name is taken from the URL as been the last but one string from the URL, after you split the URL based on '/' character. Than append .html to the filename.

line3: Open the defined file to write data inside as binary mode, 'wb'

line4: write HTML data into file taken from the response.body.